# three.js mobile touch allow body scroll

Tags: javascript, three.js

So on mobile when rotating the document gets stuck there and you are unable to scroll the body is there a workaround for this?
you can see what I mean if you test this on mobile: https://ui-unicorn.co.uk/resume/
you can't scroll past the canvas after rotating the scene to view the below content...
would a div over the top of the canvas work would you still be able to rotate the scene even if a div is over the top of it?

the current div over the top of it is set to `pointer-events:none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it in the orbit controls js there is `event.preventDefault();` 
in the onTouchStart function simply remove it to enable scrolling